# Rules for managing CGImageRef memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

What are the rules for managing memory for `CGImageRef`s with ARC?  That is, can someone help me to the right documentation?

I am getting images from the photo library and creating a `UIImage` to display:

```
CGImageRef newImage = [assetRep fullResolutionImage];
...
UIImage *cloudImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:scale orientation:orientation];
```

Do I need to do `CGImageRelease(newImage)`?

I'm getting memory warnings but it doesn't *seem* to be a gradual buildup of objects I haven't released and I'm not seeing any leaks with Instruments.  Puzzled I am.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you do not need to call `CGImageRelease()` on the `CGImageRef` returned by `ALAssetRepresentation`'s convenience methods like `fullResolutionImage` or `fullScreenImage`. Unfortunately, at the current time, the documentation and header files for these methods does not make that clear.

If you create a `CGImageRef` yourself by using one of the `CGImageCreate*()` functions, then you own it and are responsible for releasing that image ref using `CGImageRelease()`. In contrast, the `CGImageRef`s returned by `fullResolutionImage` and `fullScreenImage` appear to be "autoreleased" in the sense that you do not own the image ref returned by those methods. For example, say you try something like this in your code:

```
CGImageRef newImage = [assetRep fullResolutionImage];
...
UIImage *cloudImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage
                        scale:scale orientation:orientation];
CGImageRelease(newImage);
```

If you run the static analyzer, it will issue the following warning for the `CGImageRelease(newImage);` line:

> Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not
>   owned at this point by the caller

Note that you will get this warning regardless of whether your project is set to use Manual Reference Counting or ARC.

In contrast, the documentation for the [`CGImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBitmapImageRep/CGImage) method of `NSBitmapImageRep`, for example, makes the fact that the `CGImageRef` returned is autoreleased more clear:

> **CGImage**
>
> Returns a Core Graphics image object from the receiver’s
>   current bitmap data.
>
> `- (CGImageRef)CGImage`
>
> **Return Value**
>
> Returns an autoreleased `CGImageRef` opaque type based on the receiver’s
>   current bitmap data.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer.  Static analyzer.  Got to remember to do that more often.

Comment: You just need to remember the Core Foundation memory management rules. If the function name has "Create" in it, then you manage its memory; if not, then you don't.